# WebSphere app server 7.0 GUI admin console and MBeans

Tags: websphere, mbeans

I am new to WAS, and currently using WAS 7.0 The application I am deploying in WAS registers some MBeans when it starts up , I would like to know how to monitor/get info related to these registered MBeans from the admin console( GUI) of WAS. I see many options there in the admin console, but getting confused where to find the info related to MBeans that got registered within the WAS JMX Infrastructure when the application started up? or is it only possible programmatically to obtain it? If you can suggest some resources, it will be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You could get to these mbeans you've registered through either:

1. JConsole - A bit tricky to connect to WAS with, here's my batch for running it:
   echo URL connection string is: service:jmx:iiop://you-hostname-here:2809/jndi/JMXConnector

   set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\IBM\SDP\jdk
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;tools.jar;com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar
   "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\bin\jconsole.exe" -J-Djava.class.path=%CLASSPATH%
2. WSAdmin script - example:
   beanNameString = AdminControl.queryNames('type=youMbeanName,*')
   print AdminControl.getAttribute(beanNameString, 'someAttribute')
   AdminControl.invoke(beanNameString, 'someMethod',  'parameter1')
3. programatically.
   I'll leave this to you :)